# Custom surveillance protection

Tags: network

I want to make a secure network because of government surveillance.

1. Is there a way I can configure or build some type of custom hardware to be able to detect and to access the network, but only using that hardware the network becomes visible. Is it possible to make the network access be controlled using custom nic for example.
2. Is it possible to make the network behind a network to prevent traffic analysis.
3. What security measures should be taken to secure and hide a darknet

Comment: Do you want Internet access to that secret network? Do you want that secret network to access the Internet?

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to make a network where it is not possible to tell you are communicating.  You can build a network that will hide what you are communicating or even make it look like you are communicating something else.  You can make it impossible to tell who the end user of your communication is if you have enough participants, but you can't make it so it can't be noticed that you are using that network.

Any form of communication involves sending messages and those messages can be observed by not only the recipient but the attacker.  The best you can do is make it look innocuous or unintelligible.

Comment: +1 The most secure computer is the one that is powered off and buried in concrete. Even then i bet within 10 years there will some side channel attack on the background radiation of concrete.

Comment: @AlexH - no one has yet broken my /dev/null encrypted volume.  Unfortunately, I seem to have trouble reading anything back from it.

Answer (score 0):

Why doing so much work when you can just use VPN services, or heck even use TOR which run on top of the internet. If it is just for the purpose of bypassing government censorship, they will do the trick. Might even consider Tails, which is an OS that gives you a private environment out of box and bootable from USB. https://tails.boum.org/

Answer (score 0):

Because your requirements are so vague, I can answer your question with this design:

1. Set up VirtualBox on a computer
2. Create as many VMs as I need
3. Configure the VirtualBox networking to not allow outside access

In this way, I can only use the host computer to access the virtual network, and no outside parties know it's there, if I'm communicating with it, or what the communication is. You can accomplish this on a laptop (with enough RAM and hard drive space) and carry this around with you wherever you go.

If you want to access this secret network from the Internet, you can remote into the host machine (Remote Desktop, VNC, TeamViewer, etc.).

Note that you could do this with a physical network too, you just need a gateway computer that is the only access to the network and you remote into the gateway.

The problem with this setup is that the secret network cannot access the outside world at all. You can access it, but it cannot access you.